# Replace a value in an object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, replace, foreach

I would like to replace a variable in an object, but without knowing the variable's key... eg.:

```
var parameters = new Object();
    parameters.startregion = null;
    parameters.fx_adultnum = 2;
```

... bit later

```
$adultnum.change(function(){ setParameters("fx_adultnum", $adultnum.val() );});
```

and the setParameters function (what is absolutely don't work :P

```
function setParameters(v, value){
    console.log(parameters);
    $.each(parameters, function(key, val) {
        if (key == v) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(val);
            $(this).val(value); // <-- not works
            }
    });
    console.log(parameters);
}
```

I would like to replace fx_adultnum's value to 4 for example.
Could you help in this for meh? Thanks much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access an object's property by name with a simple index:

```
this[val] = value;
```

Just note that in `$.each` the `this` context is set to the value you're currently iterating.  Did you really mean:

```
v[key] = val;
```

You might also look at jQuery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function

```
var A = { "x": 1, "y": 2 };
var B = { "y": "3", "z": 12 };

$.extend(A, B);

now A is { "x" : 1, "y": "3", "z": 12 }
```

Or if you want to get this same result, **without** modifying A, then you could do:

```
var newObj = $.extend({}, A, B);
```

Comment: @Répás - Not at all - I've asked this same question before when I was learning :)

Comment: yep, i using extend simply forgot this method bah. ^^